# How do I use $_ inside nested loops?

Tags: powershell

If I have 2 nested loops, how do I refer to current item in outer loop inside inner loop? Is it possible?

```
$arrayA = @(1..10)
$arrayB = @(11.20)
$arrayA.ForEach({$_; $arrayb.Where({$_ -eq $_})})
```

Comment: just assign $_ to something else: `$temp = $_` and use $temp instead of $_. also, your `where` condition makes no sense, it should be something like `$_ -eq $temp`, not `=`. thats assignment

Comment: I hoped there is some sort of built in method with `using` or something

Comment: How would you expect that to be able to distinguish between `$_` and `$_` in your `Where` condition?

Comment: Like `$using` statement which has the same pattern as question https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_remote_variables?view=powershell-6

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using the array methods, use the cmdlets:

```
$arrayA | ForEach-Object -PipelineVariable item {
    $arrayB.Where{$item -eq $_}
}

# shortened
$arrayA | % -pv item { $_; $arrayB.Where{$item -eq $_} }
```

`-PipelineVariable` was introduced in v4 (which you have based off your use of array methods `ForEach` and `Where`).

---

Although a better solution:

```
$arrayA.Where{$_ -in $arrayB}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a short example of how you can access the current value of the element of the first array within the loop of the second array:

```
$arrayA = @(1..10)
$arrayB = @(1..10)

$arrayA | foreach {

    $tempA = $_
    $arrayB | foreach {

        "$tempA - $_"
    }
}
```

Just run the code to get an idea.

Comment: please pay attention while approving edits (https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/21726823) this one was completely irrelevant because the purpose is about spaces that the edit removed